# Can't get a div mirrored properly

Tags: html, css, hover, padding

I'm making a site where div's extend when you hover over them, and when extended, they show a link inside. This worked perfectly with a div that extended to the left, however, when I want to mirror the div, and make an exact one that extends to the right, I can't get the link properly placed.

```
.hoofdvak
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            padding: 0px;
            text-align: center;
            position: relative;
        }

.linkerwrap
    {
        width: 47%;
        height: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

.rechterwrap
    {
        width: 47%;
        height: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle; 
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }   

.inhoudlinks
    {
        border-radius: 50px 10px 10px 50px;
        border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
        background-color: #BEBEBE;
        opacity: 0.4;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 40%;
        height: 95%;
        transition: all 1s;
        float: right;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .inhoudlinks:hover
        {
            opacity: 1.0;
            width: 80%;
        }

.tekstlinks
    {
        height: 100%;
        width: 350px;
        float: left;
    }

.inhoudlinklinks
    {
        position: absolute;
        padding-left: 48%;
        padding-top: 17%;
    }

img.inhoudlinklinks
    {
        width:60%;
        opacity: 0.5;
        filter: grayscale(100%);
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);  /* For Webkit browsers */
        filter: gray;  /* For IE 6 - 9 */
        -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;  /* Transition for Webkit browsers */
    }
    img.inhoudlinklinks:hover
        {
            filter: grayscale(0%);
            opacity:1;
            -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
            filter: none;
        }

.inhoudrechts
    {
        border-radius: 10px 50px 50px 10px;
        border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
        background-color: #BEBEBE;
        opacity: 0.4;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 40%;
        height: 95%;
        transition: all 1s;
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .inhoudrechts:hover
        {
            opacity: 1.0;
            width: 80%;
        }

.tekstrechts
    {
        height: 100%;
        width: 350px;
        float: right;
    }

.inhoudlinkrechts
    {
        position: absolute;
        padding-top: 17%;
        padding-right: 48%;

    }

img.inhoudlinkrechts
    {
        width:60%;
        opacity: 0.5;
        filter: grayscale(100%);
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);  /* For Webkit browsers */
        filter: gray;  /* For IE 6 - 9 */
        -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;  /* Transition for Webkit browsers */
    }
    img.inhoudlinkrechts:hover
        {
            filter: grayscale(0%);
            opacity:1;
            -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
            filter: none;
        }
```

It confuses me that "inhoudlinklinks" works perfectly using "padding-left: 48%" while "padding-right: 48%" doesn't do anything for "inhoudlinkrechts".

I don't know what I could do to manage the distance from "inhoudlinkrechts" to the right border of its parent div "inhoudrechts".

On the left side, it goes out of the div, and only becomes visible during hover. I want the same on the right side.

I hope someone can help

Comment: try to make a fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda got it working with some more distances set as pixels.

```
html        
    {
        margin: 10;
        background-image: url("../images/background.png");
    }

body    
    {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
        color: #000000;
    }

img
    {
        width: 100%;
    }

h1
    {
        font-size: 30pt;
        font-style: bold;
        font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
        letter-spacing: 5px;
        text-shadow: 1px 2px 1px #79797B;}
    }

h2
    {
        font-size: 20pt;
        font-style: bold;
    }

h3
    {
        font-size: 16pt;
        font-style: bold;
    }

p
    {
        font-size: 12pt;
    }

/* Optie met balk*/
#header
    {
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #BEBEBE;
        opacity: 1.0;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
        border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
        width: 750px;
        font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-shadow: 1px 2px 1px #FFFFFF;
    }

/* Optie zonder balk    
#header
    {
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        color: #BEBEBE;
    }
*/
#body
    {
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

#footer
    {
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #BEBEBE;
        opacity: 0.4;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-top: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
        float: bottom;
    }

.wrap
    {
        height: 600px;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }   

.hoofdvak
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
    }

.linkerwrap
    {
        width: 47%;
        height: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

.rechterwrap
    {
        width: 47%;
        height: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle; 
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }   

.inhoudlinks
    {
        border-radius: 50px 10px 10px 50px;
        border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
        background-color: #BEBEBE;
        opacity: 0.6;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 350px;
        height: 95%;
        transition: all 1s;
        float: right;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .inhoudlinks:hover
        {
            opacity: 1.0;
            width: 700px;
        }

.tekstlinks
    {
        height: 100%;
        width: 350px;
        float: left;
    }

.inhoudlinklinks
    {
        position: absolute;
        padding-left: 230px;
        padding-top: 75px;
    }

img.inhoudlinklinks
    {
        width:100%;
        opacity: 0.5;
        filter: grayscale(100%);
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);  /* For Webkit browsers */
        filter: gray;  /* For IE 6 - 9 */
        -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;  /* Transition for Webkit browsers */
    }
    img.inhoudlinklinks:hover
        {
            filter: grayscale(0%);
            opacity:1;
            -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
            filter: none;
        }

.inhoudrechts
    {
        border-radius: 10px 50px 50px 10px;
        border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
        background-color: #BEBEBE;
        opacity: 0.6;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 350px;
        height: 95%;
        transition: all 1s;
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative
    }
    .inhoudrechts:hover, .inhoudrechts:active
        {
            opacity: 1.0;
            width: 700px;
        }

.tekstrechts
    {
        height: 100%;
        width: 350px;
        float: right;
    }

.inhoudlinkrechts
    {
        position: absolute;
        width: 400px;
        right: 225px;
        float: top;
        margin: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
.inhoudlinkrechts2
    {
        position: absolute;
        width: 400px;
        right: 225px;
        top: 50%;
        float: top;
        margin: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
    }

img.inhoudlinkrechts
    {
        width:60%;
        opacity: 0.5;
        filter: grayscale(100%);
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);  /* For Webkit browsers */
        filter: gray;  /* For IE 6 - 9 */
        -webkit-transition: all .6s ease;  /* Transition for Webkit browsers */
    }
    img.inhoudlinkrechts:hover
        {
            filter: grayscale(0%);
            opacity:1;
            -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
            filter: none;
        }
```

Thanks for help anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give inhoudrechts right-padding and make the child div float right. and give the child div width: 100%;

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. When I do this, the link appears way too big, and far outside (right) the div. Strange thing is. While I have set "overflow: hidden", the link is visible outside the div, however, when I hover, it will become invisible, only the part that gets inside the div becomes visible.